# Python file sending correct way? (urllib2, PyCurl).

Tags: python, urllib2, pycurl

*Hello!
My problem is the python sending to a controller which works with a prepared html sending script. Here the problem is that upload does not succeed (doesn't even start uploading) although the script runs through. The file is a binary container file. The problem should be in the code, because other way the upload could be completed*

**Here the output:**

```
09:54:40:11     ...STEP: Upload Firmware
09:54:49:63     ...Upload was successful!
09:54:49:64     ...POST resource
09:54:50:60     ...Response: {"uploadFirmwareAck":0}
```

*So the upload "was done" it says within 9 sec but it should take about 5 minutes. With debugger I monitored that it did not start just jump over it and give the "Upload was successful" message. I have no clue why. Any ideas?*

**The code:**

```
import pycurl  
from cStringIO import StringIO
import urllib2
import simplejson as json

url = 'http://eData/pvi?rName=FirmwareUpload'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type','application/json')

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT,0)
c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 0)
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
c.setopt(pycurl.NOSIGNAL, 1)

c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, [("file1", (c.FORM_FILE, "c:\\Users\\dem2bp\\Desktop\\HMI_Firmware update materials\\output_38.efc"))])

c.perform()
print "Upload was successful!"
print "Tx JSON:"
print "POST resource"
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print "Response:"
str_0 = res.read()

print str_0
c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> PycURL is targeted at an advanced developer - if you need dozens of
>   concurrent, fast and reliable connections or any of the sophisticated
>   features listed above then PycURL is for you.

I would give http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/ a try. For me, it's always the first choice when doing some http stuff. Usually it just does what it' supposed to do in a few lines of code.

Comment: Okay, I do like to upload a binary, relatively big file. I heard there is not much supprt from urllib2 to do that. The python request falls out because of the 2.5 python so could someone have an idea what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but as I see this request library does not run with an old version of Python like 2.6. I think it would be too risky to upgrade. Do you have other idea?
When I import requests library at some point of library which requires later versions throw me synthax errors.